# ubuntu server vs desktop in performance

Tags: server, apache2, performance

Recently i have installed Ubuntu desktop and Ubuntu server as VMs on Proxmox VE, they both have the same specifications but when i load test them with Apache benchmark the server version is serving almost half of the requests of the desktop version and CPU usage is twice as the desktop version as it can be seen in the picture shown below.

Apache Benchmark results:

[image: Apache Benchmark results]

Does any one know why they are so different in terms of performance?

Comment: You will have to track down the difference in the configurations, both virtual "hardware" and apache configuration. Are they 100% identical ?

Comment: Yes they are 100% identical. They have the same (CPU,RAM,Storage, Network, etc.) thats why I’m wondering why the performance is so different